# Link comment box to facebook page?

Tags: php, facebook-apps, facebook-page, facebook-comments

I got a really stupid question. But I'm in the startup-fase of integrating a webpage with Facebook.

My question is if a Facebook page has a App-id? If that's the case, how can I find it?

What I'm trying to do is add multiple comment-plugins and would like them to be linked to my page. Perhaps even so that the comments appears on the pages wall.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A facebook page doesnt have an ID, you need to register a new app for your page.
You can create an app [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)

Answer (score 2):

If you are the admin of the page you can get the page ID.

Go to your page, click *Edit Page* then *Update info* (not sure if these are the terms cause I use FB in portuguese language).

The URL in the adress bar tells you the ID. Its the number between 'id=' and the '&' symbol. Lets say it's 1234567890. Copy it.

Now, in a comment just write @[1234567890:Name of the Page]. Submit your comment and see what happens.

Hope that helps.